# Parsing an XML file with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, nokogiri

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://www.atcomp.cz/webservices">
  <xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="file_mame">...</xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <alldata xmlns="">
      <category diffgr:id="category1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <category_code>P.../category_code>
        <category_name>...</category_name>
        <subcategory diffgr:id="subcategory1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
          <category_code>...</category_code>
          <subcategory_code>...</subcategory_code>
          <subcategory_name>...</subcategory_name>
        </subcategory>
....
```

How can I obtain all `categories` and `subcategories` data?

I am trying something like:

```
reader.xpath('//DataSet/diffgr:diffgram/alldata').each do |node|
```

But this gives me:

```
undefined method `xpath' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Reader:0x000001021d1750>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nokogiri's [Reader](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Reader.html) parser does not support XPath. Try using Nokogiri's in-memory [Document](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html) parser instead.

On another note, to query [xpath](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath) namespaces, you need to provide a namespace mapping, like this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(my_document_string_or_io)

namespaces = { 
  'default' => 'http://www.atcomp.cz/webservices', 
  'diffgr' => 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1' 
}
doc.xpath('//default:DataSet/diffgr:diffgram/alldata', namespaces).each do |node|
  # ...
end
```

Or you can [remove the namespaces](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-i-remove_namespaces-21):

```
doc.remove_namespaces!
doc.xpath('//DataSet/diffgram/alldata').each { |node|  }
```

Comment: thank you for you answer John, but unfortunately, the script don't go into the loop => so the parsing doesn't start

Comment: Also, I just tried to print out `put doc` and the result is only `<?xml version="1.0"?>`, which is very weird

Comment: it sounds like your `my_document_string_or_io` is empty